# Ошибка при компиляции в visual-c++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При сборке ранее работавшей программы возникло 146 ошибок, непонятно с чем связанных
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему

```
#pragma once
namespace lipo_lab1
 {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }
protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }

protected: 

private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox8;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox9;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox10;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox11;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox12;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox13;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox14;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox15;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox16;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox17;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox18;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox19;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox20;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox21;
private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox22;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox23;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox24;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox25;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox26;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox27;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox28;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox29;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox30;




private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox10 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox11 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox12 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox13 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox14 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox15 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox16 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox17 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox18 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox19 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox20 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox21 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->radioButton1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
        this->radioButton2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
        this->textBox22 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox23 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->textBox24 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox25 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox26 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox27 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox28 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox29 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox30 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(35, 36);
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this->textBox2->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(63, 36);
        this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
        this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox2->TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // textBox3
        // 
        this->textBox3->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(91, 36);
        this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
        this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox3->TabIndex = 4;
        this->textBox3->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox3_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox4
        // 
        this->textBox4->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(119, 36);
        this->textBox4->Name = L"textBox4";
        this->textBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox4->TabIndex = 5;
        this->textBox4->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox4_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox5
        // 
        this->textBox5->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(35, 62);
        this->textBox5->Name = L"textBox5";
        this->textBox5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox5->TabIndex = 6;
        // 
        // textBox6
        // 
        this->textBox6->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(63, 62);
        this->textBox6->Name = L"textBox6";
        this->textBox6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox6->TabIndex = 7;
        this->textBox6->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox6_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox7
        // 
        this->textBox7->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(91, 62);
        this->textBox7->Name = L"textBox7";
        this->textBox7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox7->TabIndex = 8;
        this->textBox7->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox7_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox8
        // 
        this->textBox8->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(119, 62);
        this->textBox8->Name = L"textBox8";
        this->textBox8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox8->TabIndex = 9;
        // 
        // textBox9
        // 
        this->textBox9->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(35, 89);
        this->textBox9->Name = L"textBox9";
        this->textBox9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox9->TabIndex = 10;
        // 
        // textBox10
        // 
        this->textBox10->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox10->Location = System::Drawing::Point(63, 89);
        this->textBox10->Name = L"textBox10";
        this->textBox10->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox10->TabIndex = 19;
        // 
        // textBox11
        // 
        this->textBox11->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox11->Location = System::Drawing::Point(91, 88);
        this->textBox11->Name = L"textBox11";
        this->textBox11->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox11->TabIndex = 18;
        // 
        // textBox12
        // 
        this->textBox12->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox12->Location = System::Drawing::Point(119, 89);
        this->textBox12->Name = L"textBox12";
        this->textBox12->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox12->TabIndex = 17;
        this->textBox12->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox12_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox13
        // 
        this->textBox13->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox13->Location = System::Drawing::Point(181, 36);
        this->textBox13->Name = L"textBox13";
        this->textBox13->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox13->TabIndex = 16;
        // 
        // textBox14
        // 
        this->textBox14->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox14->Location = System::Drawing::Point(209, 36);
        this->textBox14->Name = L"textBox14";
        this->textBox14->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox14->TabIndex = 15;
        // 
        // textBox15
        // 
        this->textBox15->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox15->Location = System::Drawing::Point(237, 36);
        this->textBox15->Name = L"textBox15";
        this->textBox15->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox15->TabIndex = 14;
        // 
        // textBox16
        // 
        this->textBox16->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox16->Location = System::Drawing::Point(265, 36);
        this->textBox16->Name = L"textBox16";
        this->textBox16->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox16->TabIndex = 13;
        // 
        // textBox17
        // 
        this->textBox17->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox17->Location = System::Drawing::Point(181, 62);
        this->textBox17->Name = L"textBox17";
        this->textBox17->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox17->TabIndex = 12;
        this->textBox17->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox17_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox18
        // 
        this->textBox18->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox18->Location = System::Drawing::Point(209, 62);
        this->textBox18->Name = L"textBox18";
        this->textBox18->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox18->TabIndex = 11;
        // 
        // textBox19
        // 
        this->textBox19->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox19->Location = System::Drawing::Point(237, 62);
        this->textBox19->Name = L"textBox19";
        this->textBox19->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox19->TabIndex = 22;
        this->textBox19->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox19_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox20
        // 
        this->textBox20->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox20->Location = System::Drawing::Point(265, 62);
        this->textBox20->Name = L"textBox20";
        this->textBox20->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox20->TabIndex = 21;
        // 
        // textBox21
        // 
        this->textBox21->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox21->Location = System::Drawing::Point(181, 89);
        this->textBox21->Name = L"textBox21";
        this->textBox21->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox21->TabIndex = 20;
        // 
        // radioButton1
        // 
        this->radioButton1->AutoSize = true;
        this->radioButton1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(35, 173);
        this->radioButton1->Name = L"radioButton1";
        this->radioButton1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 17);
        this->radioButton1->TabIndex = 23;
        this->radioButton1->TabStop = true;
        this->radioButton1->Text = L"матрица 3х4";
        this->radioButton1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->radioButton1->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::radioButton1_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // radioButton2
        // 
        this->radioButton2->AutoSize = true;
        this->radioButton2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(180, 173);
        this->radioButton2->Name = L"radioButton2";
        this->radioButton2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 17);
        this->radioButton2->TabIndex = 24;
        this->radioButton2->TabStop = true;
        this->radioButton2->Text = L"матрица 4х4";
        this->radioButton2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->radioButton2->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::radioButton2_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // textBox22
        // 
        this->textBox22->Location = System::Drawing::Point(209, 89);
        this->textBox22->Multiline = true;
        this->textBox22->Name = L"textBox22";
        this->textBox22->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox22->TabIndex = 25;
        this->textBox22->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox22_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox23
        // 
        this->textBox23->Location = System::Drawing::Point(237, 89);
        this->textBox23->Multiline = true;
        this->textBox23->Name = L"textBox23";
        this->textBox23->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox23->TabIndex = 26;
        this->textBox23->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox23_TextChanged);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(340, 39);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(157, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 27;
        this->label1->Text = L"Правосторонняя грамматика";
        this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::label1_Click);
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this->label2->AutoSize = true;
        this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(503, 39);
        this->label2->Name = L"label2";
        this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(151, 13);
        this->label2->TabIndex = 28;
        this->label2->Text = L"Левосторонняя грамматика";
        this->label2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::label2_Click);
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(63, 232);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(124, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 29;
        this->button1->Text = L"создать грамматику";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // textBox24
        // 
        this->textBox24->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox24->Location = System::Drawing::Point(265, 88);
        this->textBox24->Name = L"textBox24";
        this->textBox24->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox24->TabIndex = 33;
        // 
        // textBox25
        // 
        this->textBox25->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox25->Location = System::Drawing::Point(181, 115);
        this->textBox25->Name = L"textBox25";
        this->textBox25->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox25->TabIndex = 32;
        this->textBox25->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox25_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox26
        // 
        this->textBox26->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox26->Location = System::Drawing::Point(209, 115);
        this->textBox26->Name = L"textBox26";
        this->textBox26->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox26->TabIndex = 31;
        // 
        // textBox27
        // 
        this->textBox27->Enabled = false;
        this->textBox27->Location = System::Drawing::Point(237, 115);
        this->textBox27->Name = L"textBox27";
        this->textBox27->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox27->TabIndex = 30;
        // 
        // textBox28
        // 
        this->textBox28->Location = System::Drawing::Point(265, 114);
        this->textBox28->Name = L"textBox28";
        this->textBox28->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 20);
        this->textBox28->TabIndex = 34;
        // 
        // textBox29
        // 
        this->textBox29->Location = System::Drawing::Point(343, 62);
        this->textBox29->Multiline = true;
        this->textBox29->Name = L"textBox29";
        this->textBox29->Size = System::Drawing::Size(141, 101);
        this->textBox29->TabIndex = 35;
        // 
        // textBox30
        // 
        this->textBox30->Location = System::Drawing::Point(506, 62);
        this->textBox30->Multiline = true;
        this->textBox30->Name = L"textBox30";
        this->textBox30->Size = System::Drawing::Size(141, 101);
        this->textBox30->TabIndex = 36;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(719, 309);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox28);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox24);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox25);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox26);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox27);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox23);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox22);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox19);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox20);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox21);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox13);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox14);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox15);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox16);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox17);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox18);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox30);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox29);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->radioButton2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->radioButton1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox10);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox11);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox12);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox9);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox8);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox7);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Лаб 1.1";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void textBox4_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
private: System::Void textBox7_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             for(int i = 13; i<=28; i++) {
                 Controls["textBox"+Convert::ToString(i)]->Enabled = false;}
             for(int i = 1; i<=12; i++) {
                 Controls["textBox"+Convert::ToString(i)]->Enabled = true;}
         }
private: System::Void textBox19_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void textBox17_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             for(int i = 1; i<=12; i++) {
                 Controls["textBox"+Convert::ToString(i)]->Enabled = false;}    
             for(int i = 13; i<=28; i++) {
                 Controls["textBox"+Convert::ToString(i)]->Enabled = true;}
         }
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void textBox22_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void label2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void textBox3_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void textBox23_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             textBox29->Clear();
             textBox30->Clear();
 if(radioButton1->Checked) //матрица 3х4
 {   
     int c=2; //объявление необходимых массивов строк и переменных
     int b=1;

 array<System::String^, 2>^ text = gcnew array<System::String^, 2>(3,2);
 array<System::String^, 2>^ condition = gcnew array<System::String^, 2>(3,2);
 array<System::String ^>^ sentence = gcnew array<System::String ^>(3);
 array<System::String ^>^ sentence2 = gcnew array<System::String ^>(3);

 for(int i=0;i<3;i++) //заполнение массива переходов
 {
     for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
  {
     text[i,j]=(Controls["textBox"+Convert::ToString(c)]->Text);
     if(j==0) {c=c+1;}
     else {c=c+3;}
  }
 }

 for(int i=0;i<3;i++) //заполнение массива состояний
 {
     for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
  {
     condition[i,j]=(Controls["textBox"+Convert::ToString(b)]->Text);
     if(j==0){b=b+3;}
     else {b=b+1;}
  }
 }

//правосторонняя грамматика
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {sentence[i]="";}
 for(int i=0; i<3; i++) //генерация строчек 
 {

 for (int j=0;j<2;j++)
  {int n=0;
    while((n<2)&&(text[i,j]!=condition[n,0]))
    {n++;}
    if(condition[n,1]=="1")
    {
        if(sentence[i]=="")
    {
        sentence[i]=sentence[i]+j+text[i,j]+"|"+j;
    }
    else
    {
        sentence[i]=sentence[i]+"|";
        sentence[i]=sentence[i]+j+text[i,j]+"|"+j;
    }
    }
    else
    {
        if(sentence[i]=="") {sentence[i]=sentence[i]+j+text[i,j];}
        else {sentence[i]=sentence[i]+"|"; sentence[i]=sentence[i]+j+text[i,j]; }
    }
   }
  }

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {sentence[i]=condition[i,0] + "::=" +sentence[i];}
textBox29->Text = sentence[0]+"\r\n"+sentence[1]+"\r\n"+sentence[2]; //вывод строчек

//левосторонняя грамматика
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {sentence2[i]="";}
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
for(int b=0;b<3;b++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    if (condition[i,0]==text[b,j])
{if(sentence2[i]=="")//если строчка пустая
 {
  if(condition[b,0]!=condition[0,0])
  {
     sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+condition[b,0]+j;
  }
  else
  {
  if(sentence2[0]=="")
   {
     sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+j;
   }
   else {sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+condition[b,0]+j+"|"+j;}
 }
}

else //если строчка не пустая
{
if(condition[b,0]!=condition[0,0])
  {
     sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+"|"+condition[b,0]+j;
  }
  else
  {
  if(sentence2[0]=="")
   {
     sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+"|"+j;
   }
   else {sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+condition[b,0]+j+"|"+j;}
 }
}
}
 }  
}
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
if (sentence2[i]!="")
 {
    sentence2[i] = condition[i,0] + "::=" + sentence2[i];
 }
} //проверка на непустую строку
textBox30->Text = sentence2[0]+"\r\n"+sentence2[1]+"\r\n"+sentence2[2];
}




 if(radioButton2->Checked) //матрица 4х4
 {
 int c=14; //объявление необходимых массивов строк и переменных
 int b=13;

 array<System::String^, 2>^ text = gcnew array<System::String^, 2>(4,2);
 array<System::String^, 2>^ condition = gcnew array<System::String^, 2>(4,2);
 array<System::String ^>^ sentence = gcnew array<System::String ^>(4);
 array<System::String ^>^ sentence2 = gcnew array<System::String ^>(4);

 for(int i=0;i<4;i++) //заполнение массива переходов
 {for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
 {
     text[i,j]=(Controls["textBox"+Convert::ToString(c)]->Text);
     if(j==0) {c=c+1;}
     else {c=c+3;}
     }
 }

 for(int i=0;i<4;i++) //заполнение массива состояний
 {for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
 {
     condition[i,j]=(Controls["textBox"+Convert::ToString(b)]->Text);
     if(j==0){b=b+3;}
     else {b=b+1;}
     }
}

//правосторонняя грамматика
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {sentence[i]="";}
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++) //генерация строчек 
 {
for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
         int n=0;
    while((n<3)&&(text[i,j]!=condition[n,0]))
    {n++;}
    if(condition[n,1]=="1")
    {
        if(sentence[i]=="")
    {
        sentence[i]=sentence[i]+j+text[i,j]+"|"+j;
    }
    else
    {
        sentence[i]=sentence[i]+"|";
        sentence[i]=sentence[i]+j+text[i,j]+"|"+j;
    }
    }
    else
    {
        if(sentence[i]=="") {sentence[i]=sentence[i]+j+text[i,j];}
        else {sentence[i]=sentence[i]+"|"; sentence[i]=sentence[i]+j+text[i,j]; }
    }
   }
 }
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {sentence[i]=condition[i,0] + "::=" +sentence[i];}

textBox29->Text = sentence[0]+"\r\n"+sentence[1]+"\r\n"+sentence[2]+"\r\n"+sentence[3]; //вывод строчек

//левосторонняя грамматика
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {sentence2[i]="";}
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
{ for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
if (condition[i,0]==text[b,j])
{
if(sentence2[i]=="")//если строчка пустая
 {
  if(condition[b,0]!=condition[0,0])
  {
     sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+condition[b,0]+j;
  }
  else
  {
  if(sentence2[0]=="")
   {
     sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+j;
   }
   else {sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+condition[b,0]+j+"|"+j;}
 }
}

else //если строчка не пустая
{
if(condition[b,0]!=condition[0,0])
  {
     sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+"|"+condition[b,0]+j;
  }
  else
  {
  if(sentence2[0]=="")
   {
     sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+"|"+j;
   }
   else {sentence2[i]=sentence2[i]+condition[b,0]+j+"|"+j;}
 }
}
}
}   
}
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
if (sentence2[i]!="")
{sentence2[i] = condition[i,0] + "::=" + sentence2[i];}} //проверка на непустую строку
textBox30->Text = sentence2[0]+"\r\n"+sentence2[1]+"\r\n"+sentence2[2]+"\r\n"+sentence2[3];
}
}
private: System::Void textBox6_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void textBox12_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void textBox25_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
};
}
```

Comment: Код нужен. И вы уверен что "При сборке ранее работавшей программы" вы использовали ту же версию студии?

Comment: Да, уверена. Код приложу в следующем сообщении

Comment: Код нужен прямо в вопросе

Comment: Скорее всего где то (скоре всего в .h файле) забыли добавить точку с запятой. Вариант два - раньше это компилировалось с помощью c++cli, а теперь нормальным c++.

Comment: вы не пробовали оформлять код тегами?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов указала код в вопросе
Вот несколько первых ошибок, которые возникают:
    error C3083: 'Windows': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type    
    error C2039: 'Forms' : is not a member of 'System'    
    error C2871: 'Forms' : a namespace with this name does not exist    
    error C2039: 'Data' : is not a member of 'System'

Comment: @KoVadim
У меня возникает ощущение, что есть какая-то проблема в самой Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код получилось скомпилировать без ошибок. Ничего не менял.

Студии я почти незнаю, поэтому выбрал проект наобум: Visual Studio 2008. При создании нового проект: `Visual C++`/`Windows Forms Application`

После в main.cpp вставил код и собрал. Ошибок во время сборки не было. Даже предупреждений.